Tabula convert_into function skipping the text on top of the page while converting from pdf to csv
While using tabula.convert_into to convert data in PDF to CSV, the data in the tabular form comes out correctly. However, the text on the top of the pdf page is being omitted. Is there any way to include the text on the top of the pdf page in a separate column at the start or end of the table?
Attaching the sample data and the code used

Code I am using:
# convert PDF into CSV
tabula.convert_into("pdfname.pdf", "pdfname.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')

Expecting to include the blue text which is there on the top of each pdf page (excluding the numbers in the second row) as a separate column at the start or end of the table.

Any answer for this post?
